# ReferenceError: MutationObserver is not defined - LWC Jest test

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

I am facing this error while executing lwc jest tests. My source api version is 52 and package.json devdependencies looks like this:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@salesforce/core": "^1.3.3",
    "@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest": "^0.14.0",
    "fs-extra": "^7.0.1",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-replace": "^1.0.0",
    "java-properties": "^1.0.2",
    "jest-cli": "^24.9.0",
    "jest-junit": "^7.0.0",
    "salesforce-alm": "latest",
    "simple-git": "^1.126.0",
    "stream-to-promise": "^2.2.0"
  }
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This fails for every test, some tests, etc? Could you provide more specifics (or share a test that fails) on what you're running into?

Comment: Thanks Kris. This is failing at every test, even for the ones which were working earlier. I updated my devdependecy for sfdx-lwc-jest to 0.14.0 to match sourceApiVersion 52, earlier it was 0.7.1. Post which I am observing this issue.